# Summing the values in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a mongoose Schema which keeps track of 5 types of accidents every year . Now I also want a "Total Accidents" column which should simply sum up the values of those 5 columns and gets  updated every time any one of the 5 columns gets update . Can someone please tell me how to do it ?

Comment: Can you add an example of your collection?

Comment: Actually the dataset I am working on is quite large . It is for a website that keeps track of number of accidents in an area and groups the data into roughly 21 different excel sheets . My job is to make a website so that excel sheets can be avoided . The collection is something like this : 
{ year : 2020(say) , 
sheet1 : {
fatalAccidents : 12,
MinorInjuryAccident : 23,
Deadly Accidents : 10,
And so on
}
20 more sheets here
}
And for every sheet I have a total accident field . Is there a function using which I can keep track of total , something like $sum perhaps ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the only way to do it, manually update it each time you do something with these 5 fields (we don't have columns in MongoDB). :)

If you are using tools like Mongoose, you could add some `pre` save hook that will do that magic.

Comment: Isn't there a function that can sum up the values of the 5 fields (newbie ;-;) .

Comment: You need to use aggregation for that.

Comment: `const yearSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  year: Number,
  sheet1: {
    f_jan_acc: Number,
    gi_jan_acc: Number,
    mi_jan_acc: Number,
    ni_jan_acc: Number,
    tot_jan_acc: Number,}
})
`
This is what a short of the schema is .  Can you please tell me how to apply the aggregate function to get total as sum of all other entries ??

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/